(HTML/JS) Button to create report based on JSON response to Database doesn't work
Please, I'm going insane. I am currently doing a Database project with PostGreSQL using Python Flask for the backend and HTML/CSS/Javascript for the frontend. But on one of the pages where it's supposed to have two button to create reports, one of them doesn't work, and it gives the following error message in "Inspect Element" when I click it:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
at fetchProdutoVendidoReport (script.js:50:61)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

And whenever I try to fix this, like giving "id"s to the HTML form, the other button/request in the same page fails, and both of them give 500: Internal Server Error.
Can anyone help me? This is the body of the HTML of the aforementioned page (I am Brazilian, so many of the things are in Portuguese, but I hope it isn't too hard to decipher the problem):
<body>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <script src="/frontend/components/header/header.js"></script>

    <h1>Gerar Relatórios</h1>

    <!-- Formulário para Relatório de Pedido Cliente -->
    <h2>Relatório de Pedido Cliente</h2>
    <form id="pedidoClienteForm">
        <label>Categoria: <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria"></label><br>
        <label>Data Mínima: <input type="date" id="startDate" name="data_min"></label><br>
        <label>Data Máxima: <input type="date" id="endDate" name="data_max"></label><br>
        <label>Fabricante: <input type="text" id="marca" name="fabricante"></label><br>
        <label>Método de Pagamento: <input type="text" id="metodoPagamento" name="metodo"></label><br>
        <label>Preço Mínimo: <input type="number" id="precoMin" name="preco_min"></label><br>
        <label>Preço Máximo: <input type="number" id="precoMax" name="preco_max"></label><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="fetchPedidoClienteReport()">Gerar Relatório de Pedido Cliente</button>
    </form>
    <div id="pedidoClienteResultado"></div>

    <h2>Resultados</h2>
    <table id="TabelaPedidoCliente">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Total Vendido</th>
                <th>Receita Total</th>
                <th>Método de Pagamento</th>
                <th>Data de Venda</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Formulário para Relatório de Produto Vendido -->
    <h2>Relatório de Produto Vendido</h2>
    <form id="produtoVendidoForm">
        <label>Data Mínima: <input type="date" name="data_min"></label><br>
        <label>Data Máxima: <input type="date" name="data_max"></label><br>
        <label>Preço Mínimo: <input type="number" name="preco_min"></label><br>
        <label>Preço Máximo: <input type="number" name="preco_max"></label><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="fetchProdutoVendidoReport()">Gerar Relatório de Produto Vendido</button>
    </form>
    <div id="produtoVendidoResultado"></div>

    <h2>Resultados</h2>
    <table id="TabelaProdutoVendido">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Faixa de Preço</th>
                <th>Total Vendido</th>
                <th>Receita Total</th>
                <th>Método de Pagamento</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="/frontend/pages/relatorios/script.js"></script>
</body>

And this is the JS:
async function fetchPedidoClienteReport() {
        const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
        const endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
        const categoria = document.getElementById('categoria').value;
        const marca = document.getElementById('marca').value;
        const precoMin = document.getElementById('precoMin').value;
        const precoMax = document.getElementById('precoMax').value;
        const metodoPagamento = document.getElementById('metodoPagamento').value;
        
        const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/relatorio/pedido_cliente?categoria=${categoria}&data_min=${startDate}&data_max=${endDate}&fabricante=${marca}&metodo=${metodoPagamento}&preco_min=${precoMin}&preco_max=${precoMax}`;
            try {
                // Envia a requisição para o backend
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'GET'
                });
                
                // Converte a resposta para JSON
                const data = await response.json();
                
                // Atualiza a tabela com os dados recebidos
                    const tbody = document.getElementById('TabelaPedidoCliente').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        
                    // Limpa a tabela antes de preencher com os novos dados
                    tbody.innerHTML = '';
    
                    function formataData(dateString) {
                        const date = new Date(dateString);
                        return date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'); // Formato 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                    }
    
                    // Preenche a tabela com os dados do relatório
                    data.forEach(item => {
                        const row = tbody.insertRow();
                        
                    row.insertCell(0).textContent = item.nome;        // nome do produto
                    row.insertCell(1).textContent = item.categoria;      // categoria do produto
                    row.insertCell(2).textContent = item.fabricante;     // fabricante do produto
                    row.insertCell(3).textContent = item.quantidade;  // total vendido
                    row.insertCell(4).textContent = item.total_venda;  // receita total
                    row.insertCell(5).textContent = item.metodo;         // método de pagamento
                    row.insertCell(6).textContent = formataData(item.data);     // data da venda
                    })
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erro ao gerar o relatório:', error);
            }
    }
    
    // Função para buscar o Relatório de Produto Vendido
    async function fetchProdutoVendidoReport() {
        const DataComeco = document.getElementById('DataComeco').value;
        const DataFinal = document.getElementById('DataFinal').value;
        const Preco_Min = document.getElementById('preco_Min').value;
        const Preco_Max = document.getElementById('preco_Max').value;
        
        const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/relatorio/produto_vendido?data_min=${DataComeco}&data_max=${DataFinal}&preco_min=${Preco_Min}&preco_max=${Preco_Max}`;
            try {
                // Envia a requisição para o backend
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'GET'
                });
                
                // Converte a resposta para JSON
                const data = await response.json();
                
                // Atualiza a tabela com os dados recebidos
                    const tbody = document.getElementById('TabelaProdutoVendido').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    
                    // Limpa a tabela antes de preencher com os novos dados
                    tbody.innerHTML = '';
    
                    // Preenche a tabela com os dados do relatório
                    data.forEach(item => {
                        const row = tbody.insertRow();
                        
                    row.insertCell(0).textContent = item.nome;        // nome do produto
                    row.insertCell(1).textContent = item.faixa_preco;      // categoria do produto
                    row.insertCell(2).textContent = item.total_vendido;     // fabricante do produto
                    row.insertCell(3).textContent = item.receita_total;  // total vendido
                    row.insertCell(4).textContent = item.metodo;         // método de pagamento
                    })
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erro ao gerar o relatório:', error);
            }
    }


To which line in the javascript does the error refer? What steps have you taken to debug this? It seems like one of the elements referred to by document.getElementById() does not exist.

@mykaf, after I put the missing IDs in the second form, I get errors when I click on the buttons, and I don't know why: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)". When I click the first button: "fetchPedidoClienteReport @ script.js:13
onclick @ relatorios.html:27" and "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON"; When I click the second button: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON fetchProdutoVendidoReport @ script.js:82"

It sounds like this is erroring on the server and sending back an error message that your JS isn't prepared to handle. You need to debug the fetched data on your server.

Add the missing IDs in the second form.
<form id="produtoVendidoForm">
    <label>Data Mínima: <input type="date" id="DataComeco" name="data_min"></label><br>
    <label>Data Máxima: <input type="date" id="DataFinal" name="data_max"></label><br>
    <label>Preço Mínimo: <input type="number" id="preco_Min" name="preco_min"></label><br>
    <label>Preço Máximo: <input type="number" id="preco_Max" name="preco_max"></label><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="fetchProdutoVendidoReport()">Gerar Relatório de Produto Vendido</button>
</form>


So, I've tried doing that, and on the first reload it works (I also use Insomnia to check the JSON, and at first it works) but then something makes everything stop working anymore and clicking on any of the buttons gives "500: Internal Server Error". I don't know why adding the "id"s (apparently!) make everything go wrong
